# Is it possible to put the starting regex anchor in the middle of the regex?

Tags: python, regex, search

I have some sentences that I need to convert to regex code. The sentences are basically search rules, telling us what to search for.

Examples of sentences -

1. `LINE_CONTAINS this is a phrase`
   -this is an example search rule telling that the line you are searching on should have the phrase `this is a phrase`
2. `LINE_STARTSWITH However we` - this is an example search rule telling that the line you are searching on should start with the phrase `However we`
3. The rules can be combined too, like- `LINE_CONTAINS phrase one BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3} AND LINE_STARTSWITH However we`

Now, I am trying to parse these sentences and then convert them to regex code. All lines start with either of the 2 symbols mentioned above LINE_CONTAINS and LINE_STARTSWITH (call them line_directives). For this I am converting the phrases to corresponding regex, and want to do the same for the line_directives too. I don't have to do anything in the case of LINE_CONTAINS, as whatever follows it is supposed to be searched for and thats what the regex for the phrase part will do. For the LINE_STARTSWITH however, I want to put whatever comes after it, at the start of the regex. For example `LINE_STARTSWITH However we` would become `(^However we)` obviously.

So the regex for `LINE_CONTAINS phrase one BEFORE {phrase2 AND phrase3} AND LINE_STARTSWITH However we` would be `re.search(^However we(?=phrase one.*?(phrase2|phrase3)))`

My question is that is it possible to have this start anchor element somewhere else in the regex, other than in the start of the regex. Like `(something)(^start element)(something else)`. [I tried this on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/W5cEVr/1), but I guess it is not allowed. If it isn't allowed, then why so?

I need this because while parsing, it is not always possible to put this start element in the beginning. So I was parsing different elements separately and planning to put them all together as separate units in the final regex. Also, I described the whole project in order to avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: You may use `^` somewhere inside the pattern, and it will make sense if you match start of a *line*. If you use `^` without a multiline modifier inside a pattern, it will always fail the match. You might sort the conditions that must be put into 1 regex, and first process those that have `LINE_STARTSWITH`, then others, (all `LINE_ENDSWITH` will be the last set of conditions respectively).

Comment: You mean `^(?=.*contains this thing)(?=starts with this thing)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so will `(abc)(xyz)(pqrs)` be matched by `(xyz)(^abc)(pqrs)`?

Comment: @user1993: Never, as I wrote, `^` will fail the match in this pattern as it requires a start of string position.

Comment: @Ryan, so I guess you are using lookahead (sort of AND operator) for all the rest of the regex expression? So even if it is long and complicated, it can be done this way, right?

Comment: @user1993: Yes. I’d use separate regular expressions if possible, though.